# Kentico Trim in a transformation with Eval

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to trim ending white space from AlertTitle in an ascx transforamtion. I know there is TrimEnd, but i'm drawing a blank getting it to work.

The V9 Documentation has a method for this(https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Adding+custom+methods+to+transformations) but i don't want to fix the length.

Here's the transformatin code snippet.

```html
<asp:placeholder id="alert" runat="server" Visible="false">  
  <li data-date="<%# Eval("AlertDate") %>">
    <p class="alert-date"><%# FormatDateTime(Eval("AlertDate"), "MMMM dd, yyyy") %> </p>
    <p class="alert-copy"><%# Eval("AlertTitle") %>  <%# IfEmpty(Eval("AlertCopy"),"", "... <a href='" +  GetDocumentUrl() + "'>" + CMS.Helpers.ResHelper.GetString("kff.Generic-ReadMore") + "</a> &raquo")  %></p>
  </li>
</asp:placeholder>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using Trim() or TrimEnd() in the transformation, you can also set it up so Kentico will automatically trim the fields when the form is submitted by checking the "Trim" checkbox under "advanced" Editing control settings.

Like so:

[image: Trim field]

Comment: Wow. Totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to cast the ouput of Eval to a string first:

```
<%# ((string)Eval("AlertTitle")).TrimEnd() %>
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, I just got this working using something similar in script tags.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In v8 and newer, you can also use a different version of Felix's answer

`<%# Eval<string>("AlertTitle").TrimEnd() %>`

Comment: you need <string> after the eval? I tried Eval("AlertTitle).TrimEnd() but kept getting errors. i did some digging then posted here.

Comment: It's the second example in the Transformation Methods documentation.  It was added in v8.  https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Transformation+methods#Reference-Transformationmethods-Dataloading

Comment: Thanks!. Missed that.

Cheers!